# Flutter just audio how to change ConcatenatingAudioSource to foreach loop

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I want to dynamically using for loop to Concatenating Audio Source from asset or directory instead of hard coded by displaying all the audio source. 
Below code display all the audio source:

```
final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: [
  AudioSource.uri(
    Uri.parse(
        "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3"),
    tag: AudioMetadata(
      album: "Science Friday",
      title: "A Salute To Head-Scratching Science",
      artwork:
      "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg",
    ),
  ),
  AudioSource.uri(
   Uri.parse("https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-segments/scifri201711241.mp3"),
    tag: AudioMetadata(
      album: "Science Friday",
      title: "From Cat Rheology To Operatic Incompetence",
      artwork:
      "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg",
    ),
  ),
  AudioSource.uri(
    Uri.parse("asset:///audio/nature.mp3"),
    tag: AudioMetadata(
      album: "Public Domain",
      title: "Nature Sounds",
      artwork:
      "https://media.wnyc.org/i/1400/1400/l/80/1/ScienceFriday_WNYCStudios_1400.jpg",
    ),
  ),
]);
```

So how to simplified the code to show only one AudioSource.uri(....) with variable using foreach loop?

Comment: Your code snippet includes a tag for each item. Is that also a requirement for your loop? Your question only asks how to dynamically get the assets, but not dynamically get the tags. If you don't want the tags, please delete them from your question. If you do want the tags, please update your question to say where the tag values come from in your app.

Answer (score 0):

'children' under 'ConcatenatingAudioSource' takes in a list. You can create a separate function that loops through the existing values above, or through the values that are accessed from another place, and returns a list that you can then pass to 'children'. Then you can have something like:

```
final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: yourFunction() )
```